# Signature always 132 characters instead of 65 characters

Tags: solidity, signature, c#, .net

I am stumped. I am trying to create a signature using ECSDA / keccak256. In Solidity the recover method requires 65 characters. My signatures from my integrating code (.net C#). I don't know what is wrong my logic. Any thoughts? I wrote a unit test to help me test some various things but it's always 132 characters. Any suggestions?

```
    [Fact]
    public void AbleToSignAndVerify()
    {
        // Arrange
        var abiEncode = new ABIEncode();
        var privateKey = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        var publicKey = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        var senderAddress = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        var textToHash = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + senderAddress.Length + senderAddress;

        //var msgBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToHash);
        var encodedValue = abiEncode.GetABIEncodedPacked(textToHash);
        byte[] msgHash = new Sha3Keccack().CalculateHash(encodedValue);

        var signer1 = new EthereumMessageSigner();
        var signer2 = new EthereumMessageSigner();

        // Act
        var signature1 = signer1.Sign(msgHash, new EthECKey(privateKey));
        var length = signature1.Length;
        var addressRec2 = signer2.EcRecover(msgHash, signature1);
        var signatureByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature1);
        var baLength = signatureByteArray.Length;
        var signatureHex = signatureByteArray.ToHex();
        var shLength = signatureHex.Length;
        var signatureHexCompact = signatureByteArray.ToHexCompact();
        var shcLength = signatureHexCompact.Length;

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(publicKey, addressRec2);

    }
```

Comment: I apologize for lack of clarity. Have Covid while trying to figure this out. I can share snippets of other code as needed.

Comment: In solidity a signature is 65 bytes, if you wrote those bytes as hexadecimal string you will have 2 characters per byte so 130 characters, plus 2 for the '0x' prefix. So 132 hexadecimal characters for a signature are equivalent to 65 bytes in solidity.

Comment: Thank you! Having hard time processing things this morning pre-caffeine and with this Covid. Let me process this and get back to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future people, Ismael in the comments was correct. I also had encoding and hashing problems. This solution depends on the .net Nethereum library. Item of note - my data type was the sender address, so the ABIValue TYPE was set to "address". This made a huge difference.

```
    private byte[] GetSignature(string privateKey, string textToHash)
    {
        var abiEncode = new ABIEncode();
        var abiValue = new ABIValue("address", textToHash);
        var encodedValue = abiEncode.GetABIEncodedPacked(abiValue);

        var hashing = new Sha3Keccack();
        byte[] msgHash = hashing.CalculateHash(encodedValue);

        var key = new EthECKey(privateKey);

        var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();

        var signature = signer.SignAndCalculateV(msgHash, key);

        var signatureByteArray = signature.To64ByteArray();

        return signatureByteArray;
    }
```